# Interpolation from reanimated doesn't work on scroll indicator from inside flatlist

Tags: react-native, scrollview, interpolation, react-native-reanimated, flatlist

I have a flatlist with movie cards inside it. Similar to this [example](https://dribbble.com/shots/18632188-Movie-App). In this example there is a scrollview with a scroll indicator with green dots below the scroll. This is exactly what I want to achieve.

I implemented the scroll indicator according to the code on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/rvmelo/7d33a55bdda3ed203a7e29c53fcadb9d). I get the `contentOffset.value` from onScroll prop from flatlist. However I have two problems:

1- The green dots do not go back to their original size when I keep scrolling further.

2- When the green dot grows in width there is no horizontal margin between the scaled dot. Despite having a horizontal margin on the animated view.

Does anyone has any idea on how to solve this?